# PHP APC problems when storing objects

Tags: php, apc

I am trying to build an configuration parser for my application I installed APC today, but everytime I try to put an serialized object in the store, it does not get in there and does not. (I am checking with apc.php for my version[3.1.8-dev] on PHP 5.3.16 [My Dev Environment], so I am sure that the data is not in the cache). this is how I pass the data to the cacher:

```
// The data before the caching
array (
'key' => md5($this->filename),
'value' => serialize($this->cfg)
);

// The caching interface
function($argc){
$key = $argc['key'];
Cache\APC::getInstance()->set($key,$argc['value']);
}

// The caching method described above
public function set($key, $val) {
    if (apc_exists($key)) {
        apc_delete ($key);
        return apc_store($key, $val);
    }
    else 
        return false;
}


// the constructor of the configuration class. 
// It 1st looks for the configuration in
// the cache if it is not present performs the reading from the file.
public function __construct($filename = '/application/config/application.ini', 
                              $type = self::CONFIG_INI)
{
    if (defined('SYSTEM_CACHE') && SYSTEM_CACHE === 'APC'){
        $key = md5($filename);
        $cfg = APC::getInstance()->get($key);

        if (!empty($cfg)) {

            print "From Cache";

            $this->cfg = unserialize($cfg);
            return;
        } else {
            print "From File";
        }

    }
 }
```

I did a few tests and there is not a problem with the MD5() key (which I thought while writing this question) nor with APC itself. I am really stuck on this one, nothing odd in the logs, so if anyone can give me at least some directions will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is was in my code:\

```
public function set($key, $val) {
    /*
     *
     * If the key exists in the cache delete it and store it again,
     * but how could it exist when the else clause is like that...
     */
    if (apc_exists($key)) {
        apc_delete ($key);
        return apc_store($key, $val);
    }
    // This is very wrong in the current case
    // cuz the function will never store and the if will
    // never match..
    else 
        return false;
}
```

**NOTE**: 
Always think and keep your eyes open, if you still can't find anything get off the PC and give yourself a rest. Get back after 10-15 minutes and pown the code. It helps! :D